Relative path to database not working in app.py?
Can someone help me solve this problem? I have a (python) script to insert JSON key into a database (database.db) (see code below):
import json
import sqlite3

class QuestionDatabase:
    def __init__(self, json_file, db_file):
        self.json_file = json_file
        self.db_file = db_file
        self.conn = None
        self.cursor = None

    def connect(self):
        """Een connectie met SQLite Database maken."""
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_file)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def load_data(self):
        """parsing JSON/ JSON gegevens laden."""
        with open(self.json_file, 'r') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
        return data

    def insert_questions(self, data):
        """SQL Query"""
        for item in data:
            question = item.get('question')
            question_id = item.get('question_id')
            self.cursor.execute('''
            INSERT INTO questions (questions_id, question) 
            VALUES (?, ?)''', (question_id, question))

    def commit_and_close(self):
        """veranderingen committen en verbinding met database sluiten."""
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()

    def run(self):
        """Main run functie"""
        self.connect()
        data = self.load_data()
        print(json.dumps(data, indent=7))  # Print data voor debugging
        self.insert_questions(data)
        self.commit_and_close()
        print('Data succesvol ingevoegd')

# Usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    db = QuestionDatabase('../questions_extract.json', '../databases/database.db')
    db.run()

This .py file is located in my model directory. At the bottom of the code I use a relative path to direct the computer to the database and it runs (inserts the keys without a issue). However when I use the same relative path to connect the database in my app.py I get a error that SQLite is unable to connect to the database. I have to write the code like this in order for it to work:
from flask import Flask, render_template
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)

def get_questions():
    """ Haal vragen uit de database"""
    conn = sqlite3.connect('/Users/raissalimon/PycharmProjects/wp2-2024-mvc-1a4-codegirls-1/databases/database.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''SELECT questions_id, question FROM questions''')
    questions = cursor.fetchall()
    print(questions)
    conn.close()
    return questions

However, this project is a group project for school and my other team mates will have to use this code as well. The problem with using the absolute path like I have done now is - I think - that is refers to my local maps, which is different for them. I suspect that the will get a error message due to this absolute pad. How can I change the code so I can use the same path I used in the QuestionDatabase file?
Tried to connect to the database(.db) in app.py in the same why I have connected to it in QuestionDatabase. I was expecting it to work using the relative path to the database (like I have done in QuestionDatabase), but it only works using the absolute path.

Please [edit] the question and remove the irrelevant code - How to create a [mre]

If I understand you correctly, the database is located within your application folder. This means that everyone involved can use an absolute path to access the database. The prerequisite for this is that the path is created using os.path.join(app.root_path, 'databases/database.db'), where app.root_path points to the application directory. This means that the path remains dynamic, depending on the respective installation location of the application.
